# Use one XAML for all – Universal App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I'am currently working on my fist universal app. I would like to share all xaml files not only libs and use...

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
#endif
```

...for special exceptions

So the first step is to hide the statusbar of WP with following...

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
private async static void HideStatusBar()
{
  Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar statusbar = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
  await statusBar.HideAsync();
}
#endif
```

But it does not work.

And the Shared project does not has a References folder. Is it generally possible to use elements from the references folder of windows and windows phone projects for a xaml within the shared project. Otherwise I have to use separate xaml files for each platform or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know in a `Universal` app you could only share the `DataModel` and other files such as Images or such. But designing should be done separately. ie: As you said you gotta define the xaml pages separately.

For more refer these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn609832.aspx

http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Building-Apps-for-Windows-Phone-8-1/22

Hope it helps!

Comment: in this case 95% of front end code would be the same. a lot of copy'n'paste not really nice. Should be more like coding a responsive website

Comment: I Do agree with u too. But unfortunately its the case.

Answer (score 0):

As of this answer, Shared Projects cannot have shared references...you need to add the reference in each project 'head' that you are targeting.  As to why your code isn't working, you aren't really clear where that function is being called.  It looks correct, but who is calling HideStatusBar or how are you indicating it isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use one view (XAML file) and sometimes makes great sense; e.g. see http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/sharing-views-in-universal-apps.

I've just created a Universal App, moved *MainPage.xaml* to the Shared project and deleted it from the Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1 projects.

I didn't hide the status bar but used

```
#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP
ColumnDefinition1.Width = new Windows.UI.Xaml.GridLength(0);
#endif
```

to change a column definition of my Grid.